# Spring Bean id, name what different on named? what special characters can Contain in name acttribute?

Tags: java, spring

The Spring docs say that `id` attribute allows you to specify exactly one id. Conventionally these names are alphanumeric ('myBean', 'fooService', etc.), but may contain special characters as well. I want to know what special characters can contain the attribute. Thanks.

Comment: If you're thinking of putting emoji in there, ask yourself: is it really worth it?

Answer (score 0):

[Just read the docs thoroughly:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname)

> However, the XML specification does limit the characters that are
>   legal in XML ids. This is usually not a constraint, but if you need to
>   use one of these special XML characters, or want to introduce other
>   aliases to the bean, you can also specify them in the name attribute,
>   separated by a comma (,), semicolon (;), or white space.

So basically you can use pretty much any character as long as it is a [html entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), but if you do, you should provide alias.

Also see additional information about XML attributes values:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

In the [spring beans schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd) one can find out that name is a [xsd:string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#string) and id an [xsd:id](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#ID). The xsd:id datatype restricts [xsd:NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#NCName) that that references [XML NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCName), see also [here](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html).

A name attribute is a xs:string as such it can contain any character that is a valid xml character, whitespace is left as is.

> The ·value space· of string is the set of finite-length sequences of zero or more characters (as defined in [XML]) that ·match· the Char production from [XML].

So the characters allowed in the Spring Beans name attribute should be those of the [Char production from the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Char).

An xsd:id is also a xsd:string, but also a xsd:token so whitespace is collapsed, is also a xsd:Name, an xsd:NCName so follows the [XML NCName rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCName)

> NCName    ::=      NCNameStartChar NCNameChar* /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */

The id attribute of Spring Beans or any attribute with type xsd:id has whitespace collapsed and must:

1. start only with a [NCNameStartChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCNameStartChar)
2. contain only [NCNameChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCNameChar)